# weiboモジュールのインポートで ImportError が出る

Tags: python

下記のプログラムを使って、pythonからweiboの投稿を取得したいです。

```
from weibo import APIClient

APP_KEY = '294703483' # app key
APP_SECRET = 'a2ef9de0a580edb7a26daf2804d27624' # app secret
CALLBACK_URL = 'https://api.weibo.com/oauth2/default.html' # callback url

client = APIClient(app_key=APP_KEY, app_secret=APP_SECRET, redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL)
url = client.get_authorize_url()
#TODO: redirect to url
```

実行結果

```
[root@localhost デスクトップ]# python cinco.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cinco.py", line 1, in <module>
from weibo import APIClient
ImportError: cannot import name APIClient
```

もしわかる方いれば教えていただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします

下記のリンクからweiboとpythonの情報取得しました。https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy/wiki/OAuth2-HOWTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`weibo`というモジュールを提供するパッケージが二種類あるのではないでしょうか。
[`weibo`パッケージ](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/weibo)と[`sinaweibopy`パッケージ](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sinaweibopy)です。

あなたが読んでいる[ドキュメント](https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy/wiki/OAuth2-HOWTO)は`sinaweibopy`の物です。
もし、`weibo`パッケージの`weibo`モジュールを使っているならば、[`weibo`のドキュメント](http://weibo.lxyu.net/)を読む必要があります。
こちらには`APIClient`は無く、`Client`があるようです。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございました。言われた通りにやってみたら、上手くいきました。